# Scientific notation in list form in Python

Tags: python, list, scientific-notation

I have a list `A`. I want to convert the elements of this list to scientific notation. I present the current and expected output.

```
A = [0.000129,0.000148]
A_scientific = [f'{num:.2e}' for num in A]
print(A_scientific)
```

The current output is

```
['1.29e-04', '1.48e-04']
```

The expected output is

```
[1.29e-04, 1.48e-04]
```

Comment: You should use a parameter in a print function: `print(*A_scientific, sep='\t')`

Comment: if you want "scientific notation" then you're dealing with strings, which is the "current output". Floats are represented as XYZ.abc rather than scientific notation (you can pass in scientific notation though: `print(1.29e-04)`

Comment: When you print a list, you don't have any control over how it formats the list contents -- it just prints the elements by calling `repr()` on each. If that isn't what you want, you need to write your own printing code instead of using the default.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a *str.join()* within an f-string like this:

```
A = [0.000129,0.000148]
A_scientific = [f'{num:.2e}' for num in A]
print(f"[{', '.join(A_scientific)}]")
```

...or by concatenation...

```
print("[" + ", ".join(A_scientific) + "]")
```

**Output:**

```
[1.29e-04, 1.48e-04]
```